# ASP.NET MVC 4 : form input value is always null on Submit

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, form-submit

I am trying to build simnple search utility searching my Employees by last Name.

Here is my Razor View

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        Search employees by Last Name : @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Search" />     
    </p>
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
        // GET: /Employee/
    public ActionResult Index(string lastName)
    {
        var employees = db.Employees;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
        {
            employees = employees.Where(p => p.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(lastName.ToUpper()));
        }            
        return View(employees.ToList());
    }
```

Debugging shows the Submit button posting back to the index method, but the value lastName returned to the Index method is always null.  How can I pass the lastName correctly?

Comment: Thanks, the example here : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application turned out to be incorrect then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your  `@Html.TextBox("SearchString")` name and action method parameter name must match. (SearchString)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string SearchString)
{
    var employees = db.Employees;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
        employees = employees.Where(p => p.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchString.ToUpper()));
    }            
    return View(employees.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must name the variable in your `ActionResult` the same as the field name so in your example, either set the `TextBox` value to `lastName` or name the variable in the `ActionResult Index` to `SearchString`